# Weibel Exercise 2.4.3, dimension shift

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories, derived-functors

> [Exercise 2.4.3., pg 47](https://math.mit.edu/~hrm/18.906/weibel-homological-algebra.pdf) If $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow P \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$ is exact with $P$ projective (or $F$-acyclic), then $L_iF(A) \cong L_{i-1}F(M)$ for $i \ge 2$ and that $L_1F(A)$ is the kernel of $F(M) \rightarrow F(P)$

I could do the first part: simply construction a resolution $P_2 \rightarrow P_1 \rightarrow M$ and connect it to $P$, via $P_0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow P$.

I have trouble showing the second. It would really help if someone spells out the details.

Comment: Use the long exact sequence of a left derived functor for your short exact sequence.

Answer (score 2):

I will describe the whole argument, because your approach doesn't quite sound like dimension shifting to me as I think of it.

---

Let $0\to M\to P\to A\to0$ be a short exact sequence, $F$ a right-exact functor, and $P$ a projective (or at least $F$-acyclic) module. Then we get the corresponding long exact sequence

\begin{align*}
\cdots&&\to &&L_{2}F(M)\to &&L_{2}F(P)\to &&L_{2}F(A)&&\\
&&\to &&L_{1}F(M)\to &&L_{1}F(P)\to &&L_{1}F(A)&&\\
&&\to &&F(M)\to &&F(P)\to &&F(A)&&\to0.
\end{align*}

Since $P$ is $F$-acyclic, $L_{i}F(P)=0$ for $i\neq0$. Then we have

\begin{align*}
\cdots&&\to &&L_{2}F(M)\to &&0\to &&L_{2}F(A)&&\\
&&\to &&L_{1}F(M)\to &&0\to &&L_{1}F(A)&&\\
&&\to &&F(M)\to &&F(P)\to &&F(A)&&\to0.
\end{align*}

and since the sequence is exact, $L_{i}F(A)\cong L_{i-1}F(M)$ for $i\geq2$, as desired. By the same long exact sequence, we have

\begin{align*} 
0\to L_{1}F(A)\to F(M)\to F(P),
\end{align*}

so $L_{1}F(A)$ is the kernel of $F(M)\to F(P)$.